# React app, API call that fetches routes for app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hello I am using react and redux, i have my action creator that fetches the routes of the page and i creat the routing with them this way:

First in app.js im calling the action creator (using mapDispatchToProps) in UseEffect and passing the result (mapStateToProps) to the Routes component:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    fetchMenu();
}, []);

<Routes menu={menu} />
```

Then in Routes.js:

```
            {menu.map((item) => (
            <PrivateRoute
                key={item.id}
                exact
                path={item.link}
                parentClass="theme-1"
                component={(props) => selectPage(item.linkText, props)}
            />
        ))}
```

The problem is that if I refresh the page, there is a little delay between the api call and the render of the page, so for one second the browser shows "NOT FOUND PAGE" and then instantly redirect to the route. How can I make it work properly? Thank you !

Comment: Show a loading page when menu is not available.

Comment: sounds good, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is to be able to know that the data hasn't been loaded yet, and render differently based on that.  A simple check would be see if the `menu` is empty. Something like this:

```
export const Menu = ({ menu, fetchMenu }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMenu();
  }, []);

  if ( menu.length > 0 ) {
    return <Routes menu={menu} />
  } else {
    return <MenuLoading />
  }
}
```

A more advanced setup would be able to tell the difference between an empty menu due to an API error and a menu that's empty because it's still loading, but to do that you would need to store information about the status of the API call in the state.